# What is the dpkg equivalent of "rpm -ql --last"?

Tags: ubuntu, debian, dpkg

I need to list all packages on the system, in the chronological order (or reverse order) in which they were installed. With RPM, you can do this with "rpm -qa --last".

Looking at the dpkg and dpkg-query man pages, I can't seem to find an equivalent, but perhaps I missed something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ls -tl /var/lib/dpkg/info/ | less
```

Source: http://mail.linux.ie/pipermail/ilug/2009-April/102096.html